# YUI rich text editor 2.9 on IE doesn't upload the selected image

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, image-uploading, rte

I'm trying to use YUI RTE 2.9 with image uploader extension which supports the user to browse image from client hard drive as described here http://allmybrain.com/2009/07/01/example-image-upload-with-yui-rich-text-editor-270/

it works like a charm in Chrome but in IE Starting from 9 to 11 it doesn't work, for each time I try to upload image from my hard drive it says 
[image]

when I opended the file i found the response located inside as

```
{"status":"UPLOADED","image_url":"/Files/Images/Desert.jpg"}
```

and nothing appeared in the editor,

Any help? Thanks!

Here is my scripts sourcing
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @@

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/element/element-min.js"></script>
<!-- Needed for Menus, Buttons and Overlays used in the Toolbar -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/container/container_core-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/menu/menu-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/button/button-min.js"></script>
<!-- Source file for Rich Text Editor-->
@*<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/editor/editor-min.js"></script>*@
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/yahoo-editor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/connection/connection-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/yui-image-uploader26.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I tried to change the response header content-type from json to 'text/javascript' as the image uploader plugin needs but IE still asking me to save the file (which contains the response) but this time is UploadFromRTEXXX.js

I found alternative solution, I made the mvc action returns "string" instead of Json object the in the js files --> yui-image-uploader26.js I did a bit change instead of eval the response I used it as a string then instead of

> o.staus == 'UPLOADED' //which o is the json response
>
> var status = resp.substring(start, end)

and use this status to check is it 'UPLOADED' or not

by this means I won Vs IE :D Cheers :)